# Fast Esp Custom Stage Development

Tags: python, stage, fast-esp

I am working on Enterprise Search and we are using Fast ESP and for now i have 4 projects but i have no information about stages and python. But i realize that i have learn custom stage development. Because we have a lot of difficulties about document processing. I want to know how can i develop custom stage and especially i wanna know about how i can find  Attributefilter stage source code. I am waiting your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FAST documentation (ESP Document Processor Integration Guide) has a pretty good example of how to write a custom document processor.  FAST does not provide the source code to any of it's software, but the AttributeFilter stage functionality should be very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I had worked with FAST ESP for document processing and we used to modify the python files. you can modify them but you need to restart the document processor each time you modify any file. You need to search for document processing in the admin UI, there you go to the pipelines, and you can create a custom pipeline based on standard pipelines included in FAST ESP. Once you create your pipeline, then you can select the stage (python program) that you want to modify and the UI shows you the path of each script. I highly recommend you to create your custom stages for each pipeline you modify.